# Proving an extension is a splitting field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If I'm given an extension with certain properties (e.g. its Galois group), what techniques could I use to prove it is a splitting field of some polynomial?

I'm pretty clear on proving a splitting field has a certain galois group. But going backward -- that a galois group with certain properties corresponds to a splitting field -- isn't totally clear to me.

Comment: Assuming finiteness, if the group's order equals the extension's?

Comment: I'm not given anything about the extension L's order. Simply that the galois group of L:K is S3. So I'm not entirely sure how I would go about working backwards from that.